# Cannot use service in class in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to use a service in a class, then instantiate the class, but I keep getting the

```
Argument of type 'typeof SearchService' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SearchService'.
  Property 'apiService' is missing in type 'typeof SearchService'.
```

but when I change the private service to typeof `SearchService`, I can no longer call it's methods on it - how can use this service inside my InitialDataset class?

api.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { Headers, Http, Response, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
    constructor(
        private http: Http
    ) { }
...
```

search.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { AssetList } from '../models';

@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
    constructor(
        private apiService: ApiService
    ) { }

    getInitialCollections(): Observable<AssetList> {
        return this.apiService.post('/cmt-api/search/merch/collections/_search');
    }

    getCollections(searchText: string | null): Observable<AssetList> {
        return this.apiService.post(`/cmt-api/search/merch/collections/_search?searchText=${searchText}`);
    }
}
```

Initial Dataset Class:

```
export class InitialDataset {

    /** Stream that emits whenever the data has been modified. */
    dataChange: BehaviorSubject<Asset[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Asset[]>([]);
    get data(): Asset[] { return this.dataChange.value; }

    constructor(private searchService: SearchService) {
        // Fill up the dataset with initialData.
        this.addAssets();
    }

    /** Adds a new asset to the dataset. */
    addAssets() {
        this.searchService.getInitialCollections()
            .subscribe(assets => {
                let results = assets.data
                results.map(asset => this.dataChange.next(asset));
            }, err => {
                console.log(err)
            });
    }
}



exampleDatabase = new InitialDataset(SearchService); // Error
```

Comment: `private http: typeof Http` <- why did you do that?

Comment: ok edited, wasn't newest code - was trying to solve issue

Comment: OP, you might want to read up on classes in typescript here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html, in particular, the advanced techniques section and *the distinction between the type of a class instance vs the type of the class constructor*.

Comment: The point is, all these instances require an argument, so I have to do something like new SearchService(new ApiService(??????))

Comment: All the way down to the Http module which ApiService requires as an argument, and I get Argument of type 'typeof Http' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Http'.
  Property '_backend' is missing in type 'typeof Http'.

Comment: it just goes on an on.... make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class takes an *instance* of `SearchService`.

The `SearchService` class itself is not an instance, so you get an error.

You need to create an instance using `new` or Angular injection.

Comment: Angular @Inject helps, however when I try to pass  new InitialDataset(new SearchService()); - I get the error [ts] Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
(alias) new SearchService(apiService: ApiService): SearchService
import SearchService

Comment: Basically it ends up looking like this: new InitialDataset(new SearchService(new ApiService(new Http(??????))));

Comment: How to avoid this?

Comment: You need to use Angular to inject an instance with dependencies.

Comment: perhaps I can move InitialDataset out to another service with @Injectable, thank you

Comment: no, it still doesnt work - none of these modules know about their dependencies, so frustrating